# Why am I getting a ForbiddenException when trying to publish MQTT messages with my AWS Lambda function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, aws-iot

How to publish to an AWS IoT mqtt topic with a node.js 16.x lambda function?

I created a lambda function which will be triggered by the AWS cloudwatch event to publish mqtt messages. In order to give the lambda function permission to publish mqtt messages, I attached the AWSIoTDataAccess policy, it should give full access to the AWS IoT messaging actions.

```
import AWS from "aws-sdk";
var iotdata = new AWS.IotData({
  endpoint: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.iot.amazonaws.com",
  region: "ca-central-1",
});

export async function handler(event, context) {
    /* do something */
    await requestHB(inactiveDevices);
}

async function requestHB(inactiveDevices) {
  if (inactiveDevices == null) return;
  const publishPromises = inactiveDevices.map(async (element) => {
    var params = {
      topic: "device/inactive",
      payload: JSON.stringify({ type: 0, imei: String(element.imei) }),
      qos: 0,
    };

    try {
      await iotdata.publish(params).promise();
      console.log("Message published successfully");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error publishing message:", error);
    }
  });

  await Promise.all(publishPromises);
}
```

With the above code, I got the following error message.

```
2023-05-29T17:49:01.024Z    5208a53c-f0f8-409f-a64b-9e901be9aa80    ERROR   Error publishing message: ForbiddenException: null
    at Object.extractError (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:61:27)
    at Request.extractError (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/rest_json.js:61:8)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:686:14)
    at Request.transition (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:12) {
  code: 'ForbiddenException',
  time: 2023-05-29T17:49:01.023Z,
  requestId: '0779829a-7f5d-d298-f9da-08f1b6d83753',
  statusCode: 403,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 24.36546771452397
}
```

Statuscode 403 indicates that the client making the request does not have the necessary permissions to perform the operation. But I've already attached a full access policy, what am I missing?

Comment: Please share the IAM permission of your lambda. Are you trying to publish on a retain topic?

Comment: @brushtakopo I give it all access to the AWS IoT message data
`{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iot:Connect",
                "iot:Publish",
                "iot:Subscribe",
                "iot:Receive",
                "iot:GetThingShadow",
                "iot:UpdateThingShadow",
                "iot:DeleteThingShadow",
                "iot:ListNamedShadowsForThing"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}`

Comment: @brushtakopo I deleted this lambda and created a new one, using the same code, giving it the same permission, somehow it works now. But I still have no idea why it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I accidentally tried sending a DynamoDB command to a AppSync client. Make sure that you are sending the proper commands to the proper clients and your functions have the correct permissions set with IAM.